# How to TypeCast SelectMany Results

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to flatten a list-of-lists, and at the same time ensure that the list of final objects is of the correct type.  Here's an (abstract) example:

```
class Space
{
    public List<Space> ContainedSpaces
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

class Library : Space
{
    public void AddRoom(Room room)
    {
        ContainedSpaces.Add(room);
    }
}

class Room : Space
{
}

class Test
{
    public List<Room> ListOfRooms(List<Library> libraries)
    {
         return libraries.SelectMany(lib => lib.ContainedSpaces).ToList();
    }
}
```

My error in this example, in `ListOfRooms`, is:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SoftTech.Integration.Space>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SoftTech.Integration.Room>'
```

Without arguing about the class design (it's an abstract example), how do I get SelectMany to typecast each item in the final list to a Room object?

Comment: @JeremyCook, why dont you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
return libraries.SelectMany(lib => lib.ContainedSpaces).OfType<Room>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

> how do I get `SelectMany` to typecast each item in the final list to a Room object

Well, you can't safely *cast* because not every `Space` is a `Room`. *Technically* a `Library` could contain other types of `Space`s (even though you only define two).

In your design this would be perfectly legal:

```
Library l = new Library();
l.ContainedSpaces = new List<Space>();
l.ContainedSpaces.Add(new Library());
```

You can *try* to cast using:

```
libraries.SelectMany(lib => lib.ContainedSpaces).Cast<Room>().ToList();
```

but if some of the `Space`s are not `Room`s then you'll gat an `InvalidCastException`.

Or if you want *just* the spaces that *are* rooms then you can use `OfType` as suggested earlier:

```
libraries.SelectMany(lib => lib.ContainedSpaces).OfType<Room>().ToList();
```

Comment: Valid point about the invalid cast; my actual use case prevents adding items of the wrong type, but I didn't want to overcomplicate the example used to explain the problem.  Your last line is what I was trying to do (get a list of rooms)